# SQL data migration

Tags: sql, excel, database

I'm just going to use an illustration to explain my problem. SQL Migration:

[image]

In the attached image are 2 SQL tables, Table 2 is referencing a primary key of table 1. Table 1 however had many duplicates so I deleted all the duplicates using Excel and imported the data into a new table with a new set of IDs. I now have to import table 2 into a new table and reference table 1 again like before. Now in the image it looks fairly easy to do that but I am dealing with a database of over 2000 rows after eliminating around 700 duplicates. Besides manually editing each row and matching them is there any way of doing this quickly. This is the first time I doing database migration but guessing there a quick ways of doing this. Google searches did not really bear any results. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Next time when you are asking SQL question please include the SQL code for creating tables, not screenshots. This will save time for people who would like to help you.

Comment: Hi Elena, those screenshots are just examples of the problem I am facing not the actual tables. They were meant to help people understand what I am trying to do. The actual tables I am working with consists of several columns which if I included wouldn't really add anything to my question.

Answer (score 0):

To preview the data you need to delete from 2nd table please run this:

```
select * from names
where place_id NOT in (select id from places)
```

If you are happy with results you can run

```
delete from names
where place_id NOT in (select id from places)
```

Comment: This definitely helped in sorting out the data that needs to be deleted from table 2. I do appreciate you sharing this with me. Now how would I create the new table 2 which refers the new table 1. There are 2000 rows in table 2 which I have to match with the IDs from table 1. Can you please guide me on how I can do this quickly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after copying table2 into table2New

```
update table2New
set PlaceNameID = (select t1N.ID
    from table2 as t2
    join table1 as t1
      on t1.ID = t2.PlaceNameID
    join table1new as t1N
      on t1.PlaceName = t1N.PlaceName
    where table2New.ID = t2.ID
);
```

Comment: I ran this query and it gives me the error  'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.' Your query makes total sense and it should work. I will work around it and see what I can do. Thank you.

Comment: Did you remove all duplicates from table1?

Comment: table1new I mean.

Comment: I double checked, there are no duplicates in table1new. I removed all duplicates before copying the data to the new table.